# Nice way to loop directorys and files

Tags: bash, loops, find, directory

I'm, trying to loop through a set of folders, and if a file in one (or more) of them is newer than a specific date, it should show that folder and the file(s) in it, something like this;

(date is a week old)

```
Folder 1
  file 1
*Folder 2 (no files matching the date, should not be visible/echo'ed)*
Folder 3
  file 1
  file 2
Folder 4
  file 1
```

How to achieve this? My example code is:

```bsh
#!/opt/bin/bash
#
# CurrentTvList.sh
# File for generating a current list of stored tvshows on my nas
# Patrick Osterlund
# 

#set -x
#trap read debug

# Settings
#
NEWTMPFOLDER="/volume1/tmp/tvtemps/"
NEWTMPFILE="TmpTvlisting.txt"
SIMPLER=$NEWTMPFOLDER$NEWTMPFILE
SMALL=2
MEDIUM=14
LARGE=30

# Clear screen; remove later
clear

#check if dir exists
mkdir -p ${NEWTMPFOLDER}

#check if file exists
if [ -f $SIMPLER ];
then
   echo "File: $NEWTMPFILE exists in $NEWTMPFOLDER" $'\n'

   FILEDATE=$(date -r $SIMPLER)
    #Check if file is newer than the existing one
    if [[ $SIMPLER -nt $FILEDATE ]]; then
        echo "$SIMPLER is newer than $FILEDATE"
    else
        echo "file created $FILEDATE is newer than file created; $SIMPLER"
    fi
   echo "and it was created: $FILEDATE" #$'\n\n'
   echo "File was created: " > $SIMPLER 
   echo $FILEDATE >> $SIMPLER $'\n'
else
   echo "File $NEWTMPFILE does not exists in $NEWTMPFOLDER, creating it"
   touch $SIMPLER;
fi
# Mostly for checking if all went well:
echo "looking here:" $NEWTMPFOLDER;
echo "file: $NEWTMPFILE"

# Small list
echo "New shows last ${SMALL} days: " $'\n' >> $SIMPLER
find /volume2/Disk2/!Tv-Serier/ -type f -mtime -$SMALL -size +2048 -exec basename {} \; | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'\
>> $SIMPLER

# Medium list
echo $'\n' "New shows last ${MEDIUM} days: " $'\n' >> $SIMPLER
find /volume2/Disk2/!Tv-Serier/ -type f -mtime -$MEDIUM -size +2048\
 -exec basename {} \; | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' >> $SIMPLER | sort -df

# Not in use right now
# Large list
#echo $'\n' "New shows last ${LARGE} days: " $'\n' >> $SIMPLER
#find /volume2/Disk2/!Tv-Serier/ -type f -mtime -$LARGE -size +2048\
# -exec basename {} \; | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' >> $SIMPLER | sort -df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can the `-newerct` option to [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to list files in the current directory that were modified in the last week, like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newerct '1 week ago'
```

Here `-maxdepth 1` limits the search to the current directory; `-type f` selects only plain files (not subdirectories etc.) and in `-newerct` the `c` means "inode change time" and the `t` means "interpret the next argument as a direct date specification of the form understood by [`cvs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cvs)"

So your script could look like this:

```
something | while read DIRECTORY; do {
    cd -- "$DIRECTORY"
    if find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newerct '1 week ago' | grep -q .
    then
        printf "%s\n" "$DIRECTORY"
        printf "  %s\n" *
    fi
} done
```

Where `something` is the command that lists the directories that you want to search through.

I'm assuming in the code above that you meant what you wrote in the question: that is, that if *any* file in a directory is newer than one week old, then you want to list *all* the files in the directory.

Comment: newerct doesn't work in busybox, apparently :/
But no, I only want to list the newer files, the old ones are not interesting for this purpose.

Comment: That's the kind of detail that would have been helpful for you to mention in your question, since "[The utilities in BusyBox generally have fewer options than their full-featured GNU cousins](http://www.busybox.net/about.html)." Similarly, if you only wanted the newer files to be listed, you should have mentioned that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to this forum, will try to give more info in the future :/